# How to prove this limit using epsilon delta method?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

i know how to construct a proof using epsilon delta method but as much as i have done i have to just algebraically manipulate and i got the value but i cant get this one.

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \frac{c}{1+c^2}$$

My try: $$\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{x^2-c^2}{1+c^2+x^2+x^2c^2}\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{(x-c)(x+c)}{1+c^2+x^2+x^2c^2}\right|<\epsilon$$

But i dont how to proceed after this?

Comment: Why do you have squares in the numerator in your expression? It should just be $x$ and $c$ in the numerators, unless you forgot the squares in the limit.

Comment: Fixing that will make your numerator messier - you'll get $x(1+c^2)-c(1+x^2)= (x-c)(1-xc)$.

Comment: So if i make the numerator =1 then i can prove it but there will still be a x in epsilon right

Comment: What do you mean "make the numerator = 1"?

Comment: it is greater than or equal to 1....oh sorry i made a mistake

Comment: i'm stuck  - are we tryng to prove this for $\dfrac{x^j}{1+x^k}$ or a specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$${x\over 1+x^2}-{c\over 1+c^2}=(x-c){1-cx\over(1+x^2)(1+c^2)}$$
and therefore
$$\left|{x\over 1+x^2}-{c\over 1+c^2}\right|\leq|x-c|\bigl(1+|c|\>|x|\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
When $|x-c|\leq2$ then $|x|\leq |c|+2$ and therefore $$1+|c|\>|x|\leq\bigl(1+|c|\bigr)^2\ ,\tag{2}$$ independently of $x$.

Now let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. I claim that
$$\delta:=\min\left\{{\epsilon\over (1+|c|)^2}, \ 2\right\}\tag{3}$$
does the job. Here the "$2$" in $(3)$ is only a safety measure to ensure that in any case the $\delta$ so defined will ensure $|x-c|\leq2$, so that $(2)$ is valid.

*Proof.* Assume that $|x-c|<\delta$. Then from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$\left|{x\over 1+x^2}-{c\over 1+c^2}\right|\leq|x-c|\bigl(1+|c|\>|x|\bigr)<\delta\bigl(1+|c|\bigr)^2\leq\epsilon\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $f(x) = \frac x{1+x^2}$ and taking the derivative, I see that
$|f'(x)| \leq 1$ everywhere.
This suggests that something like $\delta = \epsilon$ might work.

I start with the calculation

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2} - \frac{c}{1+c^2}\right|
 = \left|\frac{(x-c)(1-xc)}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)}\right|
 = \left|\frac 1{1+x^2}\right|
  \left|\frac{1-xc}{1+c^2} \right| |x-c|.$$

The part after the second $=$ sign is broken up into factors that
I think I might be able to bound. For any $x$, 
$\left|\frac 1{1+x^2}\right| \leq 1,$ so

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2} - \frac{c}{1+c^2}\right| <
  \left|\frac{1-xc}{1+c^2} \right| |x-c|.  \tag{1}$$

If I let $0 <  |x - c| < \delta = \epsilon$,
if I can just show that $\left|\frac{1-xc}{1+c^2} \right| \leq 1$
then I am done. But there is a slight hitch; for some values of
$\epsilon$ I could satisfy $0 <  |x - c| < \epsilon$
by setting $x = -2c$, and 
$\left|\frac{1-(-2c)c}{1+c^2} \right| = \left|\frac{1+2c^2}{1+c^2} \right| > 1$ whenever $c \neq 0$.
This only happens for relatively large values of $\epsilon$, but we
must cover all values.

So it turns out that $\delta = \epsilon$ does not always work.
But if I also stipulate that $|x - c| < |c|$ when $c \neq 0$,
then $|x| < 2|c|$, so $|1 - xc| \leq 1 + 2c^2$
and $\left|\frac{1-xc}{1+c^2} \right| \leq 2$.
That's a factor of $2$ larger than I wanted, but it's easy to compensate
for that factor by requiring $|x - c| < \frac\epsilon2$
instead of just $|x - c| < \epsilon$.

Putting it all together, I have to consider just two cases:

- If $c=0$ then I set $\delta = \epsilon$.
- If $c\neq 0$ then I set $\delta = \min\left(\frac\epsilon2, |c|\right)$.

In either case I find that the right-hand side of inequality $(1)$ is less than $\epsilon$, so $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon.$

The key to my thinking here is that this is not a piece of precision machinery.
It is more like splitting logs for firewood.
The results do not have to precisely conform to an exact predetermined
shape and size; it is sufficient that they be small enough.
So I keep on chopping until they are.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\right|=\left|\frac{(x-c)(1-xc)}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)} \right|\le \left|\frac{1+|x||c|}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)} \right||x-c|$$
Suppose $c\not=0$, then we do some analysis first.

If we require $|x-c|<\frac{|c|}{2}$, then $|1+x^2|\ge 1+\frac{c^2}{4},|x|<\frac{3|c|}{2}$, that is $\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\right|\le M(c)|x-c|$, where $M(c)>0$ is a fixed constant. Hence it suffices to further choose $|x-c|<\frac{\epsilon}{M(c)}$.

Combine above two parts together, let $\delta=\min(\frac{|c|}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{M(c)})$, and then $|x-c|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\right|<\epsilon$

If $c=0$, you are proving $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+x^2}=0$, which is easier by squeezing theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $c=0,$ take $\delta = \epsilon.$ If $c\ne 0,$ take $\delta = \min (\epsilon/(1+2c^2),|c|).$ Why? We have

$$\left |\frac{(x-c)(1-xc)}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)} \right | \le |x-c|\,|1-xc|.$$

If $c=0,$ then we're left with $|x-c|$ on the right, perfect. If $c\ne 0,$ $|x-c|<|c| \implies |x|\le |x-c|+|c|<2|c|\implies |1-xc| < 1+2c^2.$ As $|x-c|<\epsilon/(1+2c^2),$ we're done.